# Decoupled Frontend Architecture and Magento

Tags: magento2, frontend, architecture

Is there anyway we can utilize Decoupled Frontend Architecture in Magento. I would like to know if I can utilize this architecture to create Magento modules or convert my existing extensions?

Is it possible to use this with REST and GraphQL Protocol?

[Here is the information on architecture](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/FEDX/pages/790692200/Decoupled+Frontend+Architecture)

If anyone gets an idea to utilize it with Magento 2, please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the frontend on additional technology like ReactJS / Angular JS with REST service support. Magento 2 supports REST where you can share all the store information like catalog, order, customer.

Its simply called as Headless Commerce. Admin needs to manage all store details on magento end and End user will access the site which is built on other frontend technologies. This is bit costly.